# Java: Please tell Me what's wrong?

Tags: java

Here's the code:

```
System.out.println("Qualifies for instate rate: ");
instate = keyboard.nextLine();
while((instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false || instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false))
{
    System.out.println("Enter either yes or no:");
    instate = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

My problem is the output is never-ending; here's the output

```
Enter either yes or no:
no
Enter either yes or no:
no
Enter either yes or no:
yes
Enter either yes or no:
yup
Enter either yes or no:
```

It doesn't even matter what I enter in the keyboard.
Please tell me the problem and possible solutions.

Comment: false || true == true

Comment: Besides, changing your loop into `do`-`while` will be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
System.out.println("Qualifies for instate rate: ");
instate = keyboard.nextLine();
while((instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false || instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false))
{
    System.out.println("Enter either yes or no:");
    instate = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

To:

```
System.out.println("Qualifies for instate rate: ");
instate = keyboard.nextLine();
while((instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false && instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false))
{
    System.out.println("Enter either yes or no:");
    instate = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Should clean up stuff like while((instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false && instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false)) as well. each of those conditions evaluates to a boolean, so comparing a boolean with another boolean is redundant and potentially confusing.

Comment: But this will always be false. Instate can't be both yes and no.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Hey I was asked to fix it optimizing it wasn't in the job description

Comment: @jiija if one of them returns true it exits the loop, that is to say, if you input yes or no it exits the loop

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian I will accept your answer. I have to wait for 4 mins for some reason. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 1):

**Change your condition inside the while loop to be :**

```
(instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false && instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false)
```

**It because of DeMorgan's Rule in Boolean Algebra:**

```
!A || !B = !(A && B)
!A && !B = !(A || B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to the following:

```
!Arrays.asList(new String[]{"yes", "no"}).contains(instate.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop condition:

```
while((instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false || instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false))
{
    System.out.println("Enter either yes or no:");
    instate = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

You have it testing if either "yes" is not the input or "no" is not the input, so if they type "yes", it will see that they didn't type "no", then repeat the loop, and if they typed "no", it will see that yes was not typed and repeat again. Change the `||` operator to the `&&` operator so it makes sure that if either "yes" or "no" is typed, and if neither is typed, then it will repeat.

```
while((instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == false && instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no") == false))
{
    System.out.println("Enter either yes or no:");
    instate = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this line `instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` already returns a `boolean` so you don't need to compare it again.. try this.

```
while((!instate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) && (!instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no")))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the boolean expression in the while condition will always be true. "instate" cannot be "yes" and "no" at the same time. If you like to terminate the loop on "no" input, try

```
while (!instate.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
}
```